# Не работает код игры

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pешил сделать игру "Камень, Ножницы, Бумага"
В итоге при ответе на input программа завершается, никак не могу понять в чем ошибка.
Код:

```
import random
wins = 0
lose = 0
run = True

try:
    while run == True:
        bot = random.randint(1, 3)
        question = int (input ("Камень, Ножницы, Бумага (1-3): "))
        run = False
        if bot == "1" and question == "1":
            print ("Ничья")
            run = True
        elif bot == "1" and question == "2":
            print ("Проигрыш")
            print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
            run = True
        elif bot == "1" and question == "3":
            print ("Победа")
            print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
            run = True

        if bot == "2" and question == "1": 
            print ("Победа")
            print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
            run = True

        elif bot == "2" and question == "2":
            print ("Ничья")
            run = True

        elif bot == "2" and question == "3":
            print ("Проигрыш")
            print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
            run = True

        if bot == "3" and question == "1":
            print ("Проигрыш")
            print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
            run = True

        elif bot == "3" and question == "2":
            print ("Победа")
            print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
            run = True
        elif bot == "3" and question == "3":
            print ("Ничья")
            run = True

except ValueError:
    print ("Похоже вы ввели не число.")
    run = True
```

Comment: Замените все `bot == "1" and question == "1"` на `bot == 1 and question == 1`

Comment: у вас bot и question имеют int значения, а Вы сравниваете их со строкой, сделайте так как Вам написал @S.Nick

Comment: Что будет, если пользователь введет число 7? Что программа должна делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
wins = 0
lose = 0
run = True

try:
    while run == True:
        bot = random.randint(1, 3)
        question = int (input ("Камень, Ножницы, Бумага (1-3): "))
        run = False
        if bot == 1 and question == 1:
            print ("Ничья")
            run = True
        elif bot == 1 and question == 2:
            print ("Проигрыш")
            run = True
            lose+=1
        elif bot == 1 and question == 3:
            print ("Победа")
            run = True
            wins+=1
        if bot == 2 and question == 1:
            print ("Победа")
            run = True
            wins+=1
        elif bot == 2 and question == 2:
            print ("Ничья")
            run = True
        elif bot == 2 and question == 3:
            print ("Проигрыш")
            run = True
            lose+=1
        if bot == 3 and question == 1:
            print ("Проигрыш")
            run = True
            lose+=1
        elif bot == 3 and question == 2:
            print ("Победа")
            run = True
            wins+=1
        elif bot == 3 and question == 3:
            print ("Ничья")
            run = True
        print ("Очки: ",wins,lose)
except ValueError:
    print ("Похоже вы ввели не число.")
    run = True
```

Comment: Выполнится только один блок if. Зачем вам переменные wins или lose, если достаточно лишь одной boolean переменной(isWin)?

Comment: @Miron Выполнятся все if elif, в коде у nann были такие переменные, я только подправил их

Comment: Я имел ввиду содержимое блока(если введенное значение 1<=X<=3 ). Однако, лучше было бы исправить это. Излишний код.